# 331200-byte external allocation too large for this process

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to set bitmap on imageview,but will give me errors,here i have paste my logcat

```
 03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:477)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:444)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:498)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:473)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at nl.codestone.cookbook.incomingcallinterceptor.IncomingCallInterceptor.onReceive(IncomingCallInterceptor.java:81)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.a
pp.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-19 15:49:47.675: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have tried below code.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        options.inScaled = false;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image1);

        overlayedButton.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to test in a real device and not in emulator.

Try to add

```
android:largeHeap
```

[in your manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap)

Consider to reduce the size of your starting image

Comment: Thank you for yr answer.
I am facing issue bcs of heap size of emulator if i set the heap size>16 then its work fine.although my code is properly working in devices,but i dont want to take chance i want to maje stable code.

Comment: Consider that an heap size < 16 it's difficult to find in a real device. If your code works on heapsize > 16, you can consider it a stable code. However, you can try to add more drawable for different resolution